# Connect Travis and Coverity with Java Gradle Project on Github

Tags: java, github, gradle, travis-ci, coverity

I have made a public project on Github and I want to connect it to Coverity by Travis.
It's mod to minecraft with forge.

My .treavis.yml looks like that:

```
    language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk7
  - oraclejdk7

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew

install: ./gradlew setupCIWorkspace -S
script: ./gradlew build -S

env:
 global:
   - secure: "XXX"

addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: "Group/xxxx"
    notification_email: a@mail
    build_command_prepend: "./gradlew setupCIWorkspace -S"
    build_command: "./gradlew build -S"
    branch_pattern: coverity_scan

branches:
  only:
    - master
    - coverity-scan
```

Travis looks like working fine.

I followed tutorial on Coverity but it seems to not exchanging data.

Have I forgot something?

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: I give up with that, because it's not fully free. I use now my own jenkins server with pmd and findbugs.

Comment: Could you please read my problem and tell if my plan will work?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759088/run-coverity-scan-for-every-travis-pull-request-build

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace "XXX" by your COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN.

Your token can be found in your project from your [dashboard](https://scan.coverity.com/dashboard)

[Scan coverity documentation about Travis CI](https://scan.coverity.com/travis_ci)