# Run Coverity scan for every Travis pull request build

Tags: github, travis-ci, coverity

I want to automate student assignment grading system as much as possible. Ideally these steps will be taken when submitting the assignment.

1. Student forks my **Github** repository and modifies files
2. Student pushes the local code to his repository and creates pull request
3. **Travis CI** detects pull request and run *Pull Request build*
4. If code builds successfully, **Coverity** runs static code analysis for the pull request
5. Student gets build status from the **Github** pull request page

I've successfully set Travis builds for every pull request in my repo. I have successfully run Coverity scan via Travis for every commit on my repo. But I can't trigger Coverity scans for pull request, only Travis builds are run. Can I fix this problem and maintain Coverity scan report for every pull request?

This is my `.travis.yml`

```
language: c
compiler: gcc

env:
  global:
   # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
   #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
   - secure: "WHkT1bLbpz8VA8tl+qyZvWHLg7YvnMPhCNXCEAQQaklcDq8HQ7glIrrs35VnTDfs09tVgkPbgsAfwBuwxqkmmxWaquW0AHdb6cefNpQVj2ovUriQVNBFmjfte9Bbq0NWKoLp+4IY/3IDfLoUOekOIDXuQtkJhNvX1zkkt21lSeo="

addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: "Freeuni-CN101-2014/midterm"
      description: "Build submitted via Travis CI"
    notification_email: example@mail.com
    build_command_prepend: ""
    build_command:   "make"
    branch_pattern: "*"

script: make
```

Travis output of pull request [here](https://travis-ci.org/Freeuni-CN101-2014/midterm/builds/40043652)

Travis output after I merged the pull request with the main branch [here](https://travis-ci.org/Freeuni-CN101-2014/midterm/builds/40043889)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Coverity support and they replied

> The trigger for Coverity Scan happens for the specific branch and not
>   for the pull request, and specially the branch that is mentioned in
>   .travis.yml

### UPDATE

With user @Admaster's help I started playing with Jenkins and [cppcheck](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cppcheck+Plugin) plugin. Jenkins is scanning pull requests successfully without setting build status to Github commits(Travis does set).

Example
[image]

So I continued experimenting with Travis and came over [this](https://github.com/pcolby/libqtaws/blob/master/.travis.yml#start-of-content) repo. I changed my `.travis.yml` file that looks like this

```
language: c
compiler: gcc

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq cppcheck

script:
  - cppcheck --error-exitcode=1 --quiet .
  - make
```

cppcheck may be less effective then Coverity, but it's sufficient for students' assignments.

Comment: Can someone suggest which cloud tool supports pull request code analysis?

Comment: Sonar (https://about.sonarcloud.io/) supports static analysis and has no problem running on every commit/PR.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest not using Coverity, because free account has a lots of limits.
Better is to use Jenkins.
I will try to make configuration espacially for You.
Jenkins support pull requests on github

Comment: I've been struggling with Jenkins today using [this](http://www.kabisa.nl/building-github-pull-requests-with-jenkins/) tutorial

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get to the office. Thanks

Comment: how is this answer going to help anybody in the future - ever? if you want to help privately, please do so privately - but don't do it via a "Answer".

Comment: This makes no sense, Jenkins can do the same type of statical analysis as Coverity does? How? Jenkins doesn't solve that out of the box. Also if it did, you need to host it yourself, Coverity is a free and hosted service.